# Java (JLabel spacing)

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, indentation

I want the JLabel to display `"hi,      my name is Bob"`

However, when I coded:
`JLabel.setText("hi,    my name is Bob");`

the spaces are "consumed" and the output will read
`"hi, my name is bob"`

Can anyone please help me on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are the spaces consumed in that example?

Comment: I'm with the Chief above. I don't see the spaces being consumed.

Comment: A space isn't as wide as other characters. Maybe you want a `Monospaced` font? `label.setFont( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 10) )`.

Comment: I think camickr has figured out the problem. But I wouldn't recommend using spaces for the layout, can't you just use a label that says "hi," and a second one with "my name is Bob"?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways that both have the same effect.  One sets the font to `MONOSPACED` while the other marks the text as HTML preformatted (which also uses a monospaced font & preserves spaces and tabs).

```
String TEXT = "hi,      my name is Bob";
 // ...

JLabel l = new JLabel(TEXT);
l.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, l.getFont().getSize()));
ui.add(l);
ui.add(new JLabel("<html><body><pre>" + TEXT));
```

Having said that, I agree with @Madonah & @maraca that this is best handled in two labels, using layouts (borders and padding) to achieve the required result.